# Doubts Regarding AlarmManager - Android

Tags: java, android

I have some doubts that I would like to clear regarding the AlarmManager class in Android.
I have an app that needs to:

1. Allow the user to set a time.
2. Start an alarm.
3. Then, even if the app is closed, it should start up on the preset time and do a certain function (like `button.performClick()`) in the main activity.

So, I have successfully created an activity called `alarm.java`, created the layout in `res\layout` and added it to `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also, I have successfully set the alarm as follows in my `alarm.java` class:

```
onCreate(){
     alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
     pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), ALARM_ID, intent, 0);
 }
```

---

```
onClick(){
     cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
     cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
     alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm Set For " + hour + ":" + minute + " " + ampm, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

---

Now, in my `MyActivity.java` class, which is the main activity, I have added the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
 public BroadcastReceiver AlarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /*This is the part I got from SO for starting an activity from `BroadcastReceiver`
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.kanishka.nightstalker.homeautomation", "com.kanishka.nightstalker.homeautomation.MainActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);*/
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "APP STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        button.performClick();
    }
};
```

---

Obviously, this method isn't working as I see no `Toast` popping up after elapsed time. I kinda understand what the issue is, and I should be using a `Service` for this. But from what I know, `AlarmManager` itself runs in the background and SHOULD trigger the `BroadcastReceiver` of `MyActivity.java` on elapsed time. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Where am I going wrong?

1. You are using `setInexactRepeating()`. Here, "inexact" means "not exact", and so the alarm will occur sometime within `INTERVAL_DAY` of your requested time.
2. You are taking the current time, then setting the hour and minute, which could result in a time in the past.
3. You are creating an `Intent` for `MyActivity`, which is probably not a `BroadcastReceiver` (or, if it is, `MyActivity` is a very odd name to choose).
4. If you want the alarm to go off "even if the app is closed", then you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered in the manifest.
5. It is not possible to "do a certain function (like button.performClick()) in the main activity", as there will not be an activity "if the app is closed".

Comment: Regarding (5), will the commented out section help in any way? I am starting the activity and then doing the action.  
As for (2), I am checking that time is in the future before setting my alarm.  
Please elaborate regarding point (4) and (3).

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly: "Regarding (5), will the commented out section help in any way?" -- that would start an activity. It would not allow you to click a button in it. "I am checking that time is in the future before setting my alarm" -- not according to your code in your question. "Please elaborate regarding point (4) and (3)" -- you need to explain what you do not understand.

Comment: Okay, here are the steps I have taken to fix the issues.  

1. Added a `BroadcastReceiver` to `alarm.java`  
2. Added the `BroadcastReceiver` to `AndroidManifest.xml`  
3. Used the commented out lines to call my `MyActivity.java` using that intent `i` as created.  
4. Reading the intent in `MyActivity` to perform the click after everything has initialized.  

Is that fine?

Comment: @KanishkaGanguly: "Is that fine?" -- I have no idea. To be honest, little of this makes much sense to me. If it behaves as you want, then it is better than code that did not work. If it does not behave as you want, feel free to ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you explain what you want, provide the source code that you are trying, and explain what is not working (e.g., provide stack traces). If nothing else, if you are sticking with `setInexactRepeating()`, you will find your app very difficult to test, as you do not know when the event will occur.